# What is the _root_ package in Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin. If I reference HashMap in code, and then use Alt-Enter to add the import, the package gets imported as:

```
_root_.scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
```

What's the *root* part of this? It seems to work with and without it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It has to do scala imports being relative - `_root_` gives you a way to specify an absolute package name.  See the [Scala Wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Language+FAQs#LanguageFAQs-HowdoIimport)

Answer (score 8):

The Scala language specification has this to say about `_root_` in section 9.4 **Package References**

> The special predeﬁned name `_root_` refers to the outermost root package which
>   contains all top-level packages.

See the following PDF for the full language reference: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

Answer (score 7):

You would only need it if inside your current package you had a nested package scala.collection.immutable containing HashMap. This would be preferred by a relative import without the _root_ part.

**Edit:** That was not quite right, the problems start already if you have a scala package either as an ancestor or nested in the current package.