# Python like package name aliasing in Scala

Tags: scala

I know that in Scala you can alias things inside package like that:  `import some.package.{someObject => someAlias}`

Is  there a way of creating alias for package name, not for classes/objects inside it ?

For example in Python you can do:
`import package as alias`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can alias a package name the same way you alias an object.

```
import scala.collection.{mutable => m}

val buffer = m.ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)

buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Fun fact: You can also alias object methods this way.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.{apply => makeBuffer}

scala> makeBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
res5: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know how I could have not tried it. How would you alias top package, in this case `scala`, is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.

Comment: there is *_root_* right at the top (sort of the root of the file system in case of ambiguity, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/687071/754787) so `import _root_.{scala => whatever}` should do the trick

Comment: I tried that, actually but it doesn't seem to work in the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime => joda}
```

Now you can use joda as synonym for DateTime

```
joda.parse("2014-12-23")
```