# Intellij Idea requires me to add _root_. on all imports comming from my module just on my PC

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

This is a really crazy problem. On my team there are 4 developers and I'm the only with this problem.

I have a multi-module Scala sbt project, that I load with Idea. If on my code I do an import like `import recommender.commons.model.RecommendationSet`, Idea will tell me `Cannot resolve symbol commons`, but if I do `import _root_.recommender.commons.model.RecommendationSet` Idea understands the code. If I run the code directly with sbt, all the versions work without problem.

I have already deleted the `.idea`, `target`, `~/.ivy`, `~/.activator`, `~/.java`, `~/.sbt` and reimported the project multiple times.

I have new versions of Scala, Idea and sbt.

I'm getting crazy, I really need help. My only idea is to format the disk.

Comment: @moem thank for taking the time on that one, and not a rush job

Answer (score 0):

The `_root_` prefix is a way of specifying an [absolute import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687123/5519149). When IntelliJ requires it, it typically indicates a problem in resolving the files correctly (e.g. due to ambiguity). You should check if your [source roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html) are set up correctly.