# The meaning of _root_ in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two separate Scala projects. In both projects, the `build.sbt` has the line:

```
lazy val V = _root_.scalafix.sbt.BuildInfo
```

The two projects  contain several projects so both `build.sbt` files are multi-project builds. In my research, I came across the idea of a root project and I think `_root_` in the above value denotes the root project.

My problem is that in one of the projects, sbt cannot resolve the symbol `scalafix` in `lazy val V = _root_.scalafix.sbt.BuildInfo`. When I search `scalafix.sbt.BuildInfo` in this project, I can find the related jar but sbt somehow misses it. The two projects in so far as I can tell are almost identical but one resolves `scalafix` while the other does not.

For both projects, the jar seems to be located at the below directory in my Mac:

```
/Users/soft/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/ch.epfl.scala/sbt-scalafix/jars/sbt-scalafix-0.6.0-M19.jar!/scalafix/sbt
```

What is `_root_` and how can I help sbt resolve `scalafix`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the \_root\_ package in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687071/what-is-the-root-package-in-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think *root* in the above value denotes the root project.

No, this is not true.

All sbt files are scala code and `_root_` has the same meaning as `_root_` in scala. Thus the answer is the same as in [What is the *root* package in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687071/what-is-the-root-package-in-scala).

> The two projects in so far as I can tell are almost identical but one resolves scalafix while the other does not.

The problem is most probably the missing sclafix plugin.

Check that the plugin is enabled in `project/plugins.sbt` with line

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.9.1")
```